# Get time in hh:mm:ss from seconds in Java

Tags: java, time

I want to convert seconds into `HH:mm:ss` time format, so:

```
seconds = 3754 
result  = 10:25:40
```

I know about the conventional approach of dividing it by 3600 to get hours an so on, but was wondering if I can achieve this through Java API?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5500307/544983

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);      
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 37540);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: At two times per year in countries/time-zones with dst change this code is broken.

Comment: Have checked again: Well, clear() resets the date to 1970-01-01 where there is probably no dst change, so your code is correct in old jdk stuff.

Comment: Well, it was a good point anyway. Time value always depends on date and time zone. I have modified the answer so the current date is kept (and thus taken into account on DST change days). However, the question does not say whether DST shall be taken into account or not, so it is up to the asker to choose whether to clear() , or set hour, minute and ms fields to 0.

Comment: @david Thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me how can I convert time in HH:mm or HH:mm:ss to seconds using calender class ? Thanks.

Comment: @david: it gives 15:34 for both 56040 and 56099 seconds. I expect it to give me 15:35 for 56099. Any idea how can I make it round off when there are more than 30 seconds ? I tried:- if (calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) >= 30)
         calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
     calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, timeInSeconds); but did not help..

Comment: 56099 matches 15:34:59, so that is actually correct. If you want minutes to increase every :30, rather than :00, the first thing that comes to mind (well, without much thinking so it might be wrong) is `calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 56099 + 30)`.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated and corrected my answer:

In my own library [Time4J](http://github.com/MenoData/time4J-core/releases) (v1.2) a pattern-based solution ready for Java 6 and later looks like:

```
Duration<?> dur = 
  Duration.of(37540, ClockUnit.SECONDS).with(Duration.STD_CLOCK_PERIOD);
String s = Duration.Formatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss").format(dur);
System.out.println(s); // 10:25:40
```

In Joda-Time following code is possible using a builder approach:

```
PeriodFormatter f =
  new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours().appendLiteral(":").appendMinutes()
  .appendLiteral(":").appendSeconds().toFormatter();
System.out.println("Joda-Time: " + f.print(new Period(37540 * 1000))); // 10:25:40
```

My previous posted solution was a field-based-workaround (using the field SECOND_OF_DAY) which has a serious disadvantage, namely to be limited to seconds less than 86400 (day-length). **The accepted answer using old Calendar-code suffers from this bug, too, so it is not a real solution.** In Java-8 (containing a new time library - JSR-310) there is also no solution available because it still misses the possibility to format durations. Sample outputs of the different proposals:

```
input = 337540 seconds (almost 4 days)
code of accepted solution => 21:45:40 (WRONG!!!)
Time4J-v1.2 => 93:45:40
Joda-Time => 93:45:40
```

Conclusion, use an external library for solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

## `LocalTime`

The java.time classes built into Java can do this. The [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone. This class includes the concept of second-of-day, how many seconds from the start of the day.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay( 3_754L );
```

But the result is not close to what you showed in your Question.

> lt.toString(): 01:02:34

## Duration

Do not use a time-of-day to represent elapsed time. Confusing and ambiguous. Don’t use a time-of-day class and don’t use a time-of-day style of string formatting.

For elapsed time in the range of day-hours-minutes-seconds, use the [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( 3_754L );
```

> d.toString(): PT1H2M34S

That output is a String generated in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates the years-month-days portion from the hours-minutes-seconds portion. So the result seen above means “one hour, two minutes, and thirty-four seconds”.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).