# Android Create an activity with no buttons

Tags: android

I am very confused as to why I cannot get this to work. I want to have a screen with no buttons run for 5 seconds while I do some things in the background, then navigate back to another screen. Is this not possible?

I have tried to put the code to run the background items in onCreate, onStart, and onResume, and all of these methods are fired before the screen actually displays. Is there another way to do this?

**Edit** The most recent version of my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sync);

}

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    commitSync();
}

private void commitSync(){

    TextView monthDayYear = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.month_day_year);
    TextView hourMinuteSecond = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hour_minute_second);

    _application = (App)getApplicationContext();

    try {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //Ensure that we have flash
        if(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
            Camera androidCamera = Camera.open();
            Camera.Parameters p = androidCamera.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            androidCamera.setParameters(p);
            //Flash and then turn off
            androidCamera.startPreview();
            latch.await(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
            androidCamera.stopPreview();
            //Flash screen white
            //Get date and time
            Module syncModule = _application.getModule();
            syncModule.start();
            Calendar syncTime = syncModule.getDateAndTime();
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988004/get-time-in-hhmmss-from-seconds-in-java
            monthDayYear.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(syncTime.getTime()));
            hourMinuteSecond.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:00").format(syncTime.getTime()));

            //Navigate back to MainActivity
            Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(SyncActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(mainActivityIntent, 1);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Cannot access Android Flash");
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Util.appendLog("Exception occured in Sync: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Just added it in an edit. The commitSync is a bit complex, but I want that to run when the screen is displayed anyways, and it can run without errors

Comment: So what does `commitSync()` do?

Comment: Are you faking a load screen; why not a splash screen?

Comment: Does commitSync() run on the UI thread or a background thread?

Comment: added commit sync. It makes the camera flash as of now (well, thats the goal at least)

Comment: It is up now. Formatting took a bit of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this help you:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do some work like:

        finish();
    }
}, 500);
```

This run a code after some delay and you can put this code in your desired screen.

Comment: Added it to onResume() and that fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            //The code you want to execute
          }
        }, timeUntilExecution);
```

This code should execute that run() method after the timeUntilExecution variable (in milliseconds) you could use this to execute what you want to do after the delay. Hope this helps.